# toFixed() output different in javascript and Angular application

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am seeing a strange outcome for the following expression(described below) when ran in 2 different applications.

In a angular js application, the result of the following expression is `1.2`:

```
parseFloat(1.2).toFixed(2) => "1.2"
```

But the same expression returns `1.20` when ran inside a JSP/Javascript application:

```
parseFloat(1.2).toFixed(2) => "1.20"
```

Could anyone suggest what is the possible factor that might be influencing this different outcome 
Or, why is `toFixed()` behaving differently?

Comment: If that is the case it might be that angularjs is overriding the Number.prototype.toFixed method. I wouldn't expect angular to do so... you can check in the console, if you type Number.prototype.toFixed and you see [native code] then it is the native, if you see any implementation then it is overwritten

Comment: Thanks!! I checked in console and as you have pointed out, turns out that Angular is actually overriding the Number.prototype.toFixed. Is there a way to stop Angular from overriding the Number.prototype.toFixed implementation?

Comment: You would have to implement it yourself I guess...

Comment: How you get 1.2? It is always 1.20.